# What is the best option to customize Expiration bundle?

Tags: ravendb

I do not want to delete documents when they expire, instead I need to move them somewhere (like database for expired documents) as I need to store them for historical purposes. What is the best way to achieve this goal in RavenDB?

1. is there a way to change expiration bundle behavior?
2. should I implement my own bundle?
3. should I implement a trigger or other specific entity
4. or there is other existing option I am now aware of or do not have enough knowledge to consider it as option (like replication or maybe
   documents are not fully deleted in this bundle)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own bundle based on the logic in the expiration bundle.
That is the simplest way to handle this.